# Extrapolate data by two factors in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

here is the problem. I need extrapolate data from table like below.

```
sp    rd  pH count
1 dog  uniq 4.5     5
2 dog  uniq 4.2     5
3 dog   for 6.1     3
4 cat  uniq 7.0     8
5 cat  uniq 4.9     5
6 cat mains 3.1     9
7 cat mains 6.5     1
8 cat mains 6.5     3
```

in this table, there are two factors `sp` and `rd`. My outcome should be the list (or possibly matrix but i thing that create matrix in R with different length of rows should be harder than create a list) where: `list` has as many vectors as many are unique combinations of factors `sp` and `rd` and each vector has numbers of pHs for the combination of factors.

More specifically, my outcome should be a list with four vectors (combinations are dog uniq, dog for, cat unique and cat mains) with numbers `(4.5, 4.2), (6.1)`, `(7.0, 4.9)` and `(3.1, 6.5, 6.5)`.

Sorry for my english, i am not native speaker. Hope it is understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `split`.  If there are more than one group for the `f`, keep it in a `list` .

```
split(df1$pH, list(df1$sp, df1$rd), drop=TRUE)
```

Or use `interaction` of the group variables for `f`.

```
split(df1$pH, interaction(df1[1:2], drop=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `extrapolate.uni.scam()` function from `SCAM` library in `R`,

Please Check below link for example :

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/scam/docs/extrapolate.uni.scam